# Activity Indicator called from another class not Stopping

Tags: swift3, uiactivityindicatorview

I am using activity indicator from "https://github.com/erangaeb/dev-notes/blob/master/swift/ViewControllerUtils.swift". I tried using it in my view but indicator doesn't seem to stop.I have included it in my view as below:

```
ActivityIndicatorView().showActivityIndicator(uiView: self.view)
```

I using the below code to stop:

```
ActivityIndicatorView().hideActivityIndicator(uiView: self.view)
```

But I don't know why the indicator is stoping.
More of my code is as below:

```
Alamofire.request(diaryViewUrl, method: .get, parameters: [:]).responseJSON {
        response in
        if response.result.isSuccess{

            ActivityIndicatorView().showActivityIndicator(uiView: self.view)

            let dataFetched : JSON = JSON(response.result.value!)

            self.diaryDateTimeText = dataFetched["diary_datetime"].string
            self.diaryLocText = dataFetched["diary_loc"].string
            self.diaryText = dataFetched["diary_text"].string
            self.diaryTags = dataFetched["tags"].arrayObject as? [String]

            ActivityIndicatorView().hideActivityIndicator(uiView: self.view)

            self.topBar()
            self.showViews()

            self.scrollView.addSubview(self.containerView)

            self.view.addSubview(self.scrollView)


        }else{
            print("Error \(String(describing: response.result.error))")

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to show the activity indicator before making the Alamofire request and when you get the response with success or error status you can hide it, now show and hide are called at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine for me. Please try it

```
ActivityIndicatorView().showActivityIndicator(uiView: self.view)

Alamofire.request(diaryViewUrl, method: .get, parameters: [:]).responseJSON {
    response in

    ActivityIndicatorView().hideActivityIndicator(uiView: self.view)

    if response.result.isSuccess{


        let dataFetched : JSON = JSON(response.result.value!)

        self.diaryDateTimeText = dataFetched["diary_datetime"].string
        self.diaryLocText = dataFetched["diary_loc"].string
        self.diaryText = dataFetched["diary_text"].string
        self.diaryTags = dataFetched["tags"].arrayObject as? [String]


        self.topBar()
        self.showViews()

        self.scrollView.addSubview(self.containerView)

        self.view.addSubview(self.scrollView)


    }else{
        print("Error \(String(describing: response.result.error))")

    }
}
```